# Challenge: images from Hart-Segerman

Tags: diagrams

[This paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1404.6596) by Vi Hart and Henry Segerman has some interesting hand-drawn images that cry out for a treatment with your favourite TeX-friendly package. I like the concept of throwing up one's hands and saying 'forget it; hand-drawn images it is', but it's just as cool to see such interesting figures done by code.

Figure 1 c) is easy (for those in the know), figure 2 (or some minor variation on it) is do-able, but the 3D model of the cube with the appropriately perspectivised images on faces could be challenging. Figures 3 and 4 should follow from figure 2.

To give a concrete question:

Can figure 5 from the linked paper be generated programmatically? It seems completely systematic to me.

[image: Figure 5 from arxiv:1404.6596]

Comment: Forget it; hand-drawn images it is. `:)`

Comment: No way should this be CW.  It's going to take some serious work to make those (IMHO) and whoever attempts it should get their dues in rep.

Comment: @AndrewStacey ah, of course. I was thinking that I didn't want any rep for the Q, but that's the wrong way around.

Comment: @SeanAllred - thanks for the image!

Comment: While I understand that it's ok to have _some_ "how can I draw this fancy picture" questions, this one doesn't seem to be reasonable at all. The figure is not suitable to be drawn in any way but by hand or in a professional 3D software. However, TeX is not such a software, not even with TikZ or PSTricks. Therefore I think the question is off-topic.

Comment: I have used  [asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net) to create 3D diagrams. Much simpler ones, and never tried for a hand-drawn look, but it should be doable. Best of all, it handles LaTeX fonts cleanly.

Comment: @vonbrand - definitely _not_ looking for a hand-drawn look here, but a clean version with the same information.

Comment: I'd be tempted to do this as a vector graphic, and feed it into the paper.  But it is easier to do hand-drawn graphics and let someone else figure out how to vectorise it.